# If You're Minded To Answer It

Tags: riddle, word, cryptic-clues

The answer to this riddle is a single English word. The poem contains five clues in the form of definitions and or cryptic clues. The word is a common one but one of the definitions I used is an unusual one, so a dictionary may be useful.

> "A demon's numbered here about."
>   "You are a fool!" The people shout.
>   The cure? A herbal remedy.
>   That's no bad break it's clear to see.
>   There's double trouble next, no doubt.
>   It makes me slip, impels me out.

I need this solved tomorrow at the latest. I hope the two extra lines don't spoil the fun. Again, a dictionary is the only outside source you should need.

Comment: If you're inclined to clarify, is the "T" in "The people shout" capitalized on purpose or is it a continuation of the sentence with the quotation?

Comment: It's a continuation of the sentence. Capitalization is not significant.

Comment: You say there are five clues, but there are only four lines. Is that a typo or intended?

Comment: @GordonAllocman Intended. There's enough space on a line for two clues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"A demon's numbered here about."

> IMP + L (Roman numeral) inside SE (Stack Exchange is "here")

"You are a fool!" The people shout.

> A fool is a SIMP; LE is "the".

The cure? A herbal remedy.

> "SIMPLE" also means "herbal remedy" (found by SendersReagent)

That's no bad break it's clear to see.

> The first half may be referring to a "simple fracture" (better than a compound one) (found by SendersReagent); the second half is a straight definition, "it's clear to see".

There's double trouble next, no doubt.

> "There are two cryptic clues coming up in the next line."

It makes me slip, impels me out.

> SIMPLE makes ME SLIP; it is also IMPELS 'out' (a common anagram indicator)

Comment: Ah, yes, yes. The first one is good. I like that. The second one I think could be either. And the last two are better than mine, for sure.

Comment: @SendersReagent: I chose mine over yours since all but one word would be useless in yours. Still not quite satisfied with mine, though.

Comment: I feel like shouting has to be part of it, but I don't see how it could be.

Comment: @SendersReagent: My theory was some sort of homophone indicator, but I'm not sure how it would fit in.

Comment: "The people shout" is, unfortunately, just there to satisfy rhyme and meter. Ideally, there would be one more clue with fiendish ingenuity but I couldn't think of one that fit.

Comment: ... And congratulations on the solution!

Comment: @Hugh: Thank you! That last line is the one that did it for me. As for the second, I would say something like "the Yank would shout" to make that line into a homophone of SIMP+PULL.

Comment: @HughMeyers "You fool the joint as you spell it out"? Oh well, I kept coming back to "cheer" with: C=100 + here (about); people shout; and bits of thecure. The two new clues certainly help!

Answer (score 6):

My $0.02 about this:
Answer:

> Garlic

"A demon's numbered here about."

> reference to Dracula

"You are a fool!" The people shout.

> Line from the book "Vlad Dracula" by  Michael Augustyn

The cure? A herbal remedy.

> In the vampire mythology Garlic is one of the "remedies" against vampires.

That's no bad break it's clear to see.

> it's common knowledge because (or thanks to) Bram Stoker.

Comment: These are cryptic-style clues, meaning that there is wordplay involved. For more information on cryptic crosswords go to http://solving-cryptics.com/ .

Answer (score 6):

I've not quite pieced everything together yet, but based on what I have, the answer (I think) is

> "Simple"

"A demon's numbered here about!"

> This I'm not sure on. In the Bible, Jesus expelled a mute (dumb) demon from a man who was then able to speak. 666 is a triangular number and it's simple because it's a repidigit... No, I got nothing.

"You are a fool" The people shout!

> "Simple" also means dumb (foolish)

The cure? A herbal remedy.

> simple: *n* a medicinal herb, or a medicine made from one.
> "the gatherers of simples"

That's no bad break

> Simple fractures (broken bones) aren't as bad as compound fractures.

It's clear to see.

> Self-explanatory, but something that is simple is obvious, i.e. clearly noticeable.

There's double trouble next, no doubt.

> When something is simple, it is expected that something complicating is nigh.
> Or maybe this random line I saw from the Bible: "The prudent see danger and take refuge, but the simple keep going and pay the penalty."

It makes me slip, impels me out.

> I'm unsure about this one, but maybe... You mess up (i.e. slip) spelling "simple" and accidentally spell it "s**impel**?

The title "If you're minded to answer it"

> If you're simple-minded, it may be too complicated. This goes along with "Clem," the simple-minded crawdad slappee who was mentioned in the original narrative.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but you haven't quite gotten the cryptic part down.

Comment: @Deusovi For instance? Most of what I have would either be word play or definition.

Comment: @Deusovi I'm aware some isn't; that's why I feel unsure about some of them. But I think most of it fits, especially the herbal remedy thing, the "bad break," etc. The herbal remedy part is what sold me.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right on the herbal remedy. I've gotten all but the "bad break" line so I'm posting it as another answer, but I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess, though I haven't managed to fit all the clues.:

It is:

> Chasm

"A demon's numbered here about."

> Could be a reference to [Purgatory Chasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purgatory_Chasm_State_Reservation)

"You are a fool!" The people shout.

> One definition of chasm is "a divergence of opinions, beliefs, etc., between persons or groups" so I think this fits

The cure? A herbal remedy.

> No idea for this one

That's no bad break it's clear to see.

> A break that isn't bad is a fracture. Another definition of a fracture is "the cracking or breaking of a hard object or material" which a chasm may be synonymous of (probably a bit of stretch)

Comment: These are cryptic-style clues, meaning that there is wordplay involved. For more information on cryptic crosswords go to [solving-cryptics.com](http://solving-cryptics.com).